# Как сравнить значение переменной с несколькими значениями

Tags: javascript

Нужно проверить, равно ли значение `state` 20, 40 или 50. Условно:

```
state = 40
if (state === (20 || 40 || 50)) {
     color = "#000"
}
```

Можно так:

```
state = 40
if ((state === 20) || (state === 40) || (state === 50)) {
   color = "#000"
}
```

но хотелось бы как-то лаконичнее

Comment: @Макск не подходит, потому что тогда будут засчитываться те значения, которых изначально нету (например, 25, 34, 42 и т.д.)

Comment: Скобки лишние выкинуть.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно загрузить все значения, с которыми Вы будете сравнивать `state`, в массив, а затем проверить нахождение требуемого элемента с помощью функции [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
state = 40

if ([20, 40, 50].includes(state)) {
   alert('Hi! ^.^')
   color = "#000"
}
```